# Equivalent of .send()

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Is there an equivalent to LoadVars.send() in AS3 where I just send off variables without waiting for a response? I just send off the variables into cyberspace blindly, and I am happy that way. How do I do it? Or has it been removed for some security thingie in AS3?

Answer (score 2):

You want to take a look at the following URLLoader, URLRequest and URLVariable documentation:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/net/URLVariables.html

Here's example usage directly from the documentation:

```
package {
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.net.navigateToURL;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLVariables;
import flash.net.URLLoader;

    public class URLVariablesExample extends Sprite {
        public function URLVariablesExample() {
            var url:String = "http://www.[yourDomain].com/application.jsp";
            var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);
            var variables:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
            variables.exampleSessionId = new Date().getTime();
            variables.exampleUserLabel = "guest";
            request.data = variables;
            // navigateToUrl(request);
            var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            loader.load(request);
        }
    }
}
```

-BTW
Yes, that's correct. You should be using URLLoader instead of navigateToURL. I mentioned it but I cut and paste from an example

Comment: Thanks for helping. This solution opens up a new page/tab and if I specify another target like "_self" etc the page disappears. This only looks like it could work if you use the 'iframe hack' and put the results there.

Comment: I took the liberty to change your code example to accomodate Betamakz's comment. Made no sense to basically replicate your answer just to change two lines. I hope you don't mind. I you do, though, feel free to roll back my edit. (+1 by the way)

Comment: +1 for @Juan's edit: [navigateToURL](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/package.html#navigateToURL%28%29)  is for opening a new page in the browser: it "Opens or replaces a window in the application that contains the Flash Player container (usually a browser)"

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  You should be using URLLoader instead of navigateToURL.  I mentioned it but I cut and paste from an example